# Mobile Chrome bar taking up space from 100% height css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im facing a rather famous problem but cant seem to find any solution in my case. So I have this collapsible scrollable bar implemented on bootstrap but the problem is when i try to scroll this bar on mobile, due to the search bar taking a little space from the 100% height set for the sidebar, the scrollbar does not reach the end of the div therefore clipping the content. I want to know a way to exclude the bar from the height or like a workaround that would fix this issue.

Here's my html and css for the sidebar: https://jsfiddle.net/fq5b3m1w/

```
html,
body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  // padding-left: 100px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  width: 0;
  height: calc(100%);
  margin-left: -100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -100px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  // text-indent: 20px;
  // line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li .fa {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  // color: rgba(2,136,209,1);
}

.sidebar-nav li.active a {
  // color: #fff;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, .2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First Method:**

A simple solution would be adding a border to offset the extra space on top

Remove:

```
#wrapper {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Add:

```
#sidebar-wrapper {
    border-top: 50px solid white;
}
```

**Second Method:**

Creating a top a header and a content divs, where you specify the header with `height:10%` and content `height:90%`. This way the scrollbar will always fit into the screen regardless what size you are in.

**Third Method:**

Using `display:flex` where you arrange both header and content in a column using `flex-direction: column;`. Then specify the header using `flex-basis:50px` and content `flex-grow:1` and `flex-basis:auto;` this way the content adjust the height itself automatically.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you want but you could try this.

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var height = $(window).height()-50;
  $('#sidebar-wrapper').css('height',height+'px');
  $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper {
  padding-left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
  // padding-left: 100px;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
  z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
  left: 100px;
  width: 0;
  margin-left: -100px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
  background: #fcfcfc;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 100px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 5px;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}

#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  margin-right: -100px;
}


/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
  // text-indent: 20px;
  // line-height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li .fa {
  padding-top: 10px;
  display: block;
  // color: rgba(2,136,209,1);
}

.sidebar-nav li.active a {
  // color: #fff;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, .2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  transition: all .2s;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 8px 0;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #333;
  background: rgba(2, 136, 209, 0.2);
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
  height: 65px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
  color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
  color: #fff;
  background: none;
}

@media(min-width:992px) {
  #wrapper {
    padding-left: 100px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 100px;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 0;
  }
  #page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
  }
  #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div id="wrapper">
  <!-- Sidebar -->
  <div id="sidebar-wrapper" class="affix">
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-home fa-2x"></i> Home
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="/companies">
          <i class="fa fa-building fa-2x"></i> Companies
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="">
        <a href="/people">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i> People
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-handshake-o fa-2x"></i> Investors
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-money fa-2x"></i> Funding Rounds
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-users fa-2x"></i> Acquisitions
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-graduation-cap fa-2x"></i> Schools
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i> Events
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-calendar fa-2x"></i> Login/Signup
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
  <!-- Page Content -->
  <div id="page-content-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
          content
          <button id="menu-toggle">
          menu
          </button>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
</div>
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/fq5b3m1w/3/).

Comment: this kinda worked, but after the address bar is gone, a 50px space is created below the sidebar